# Creating columns in a PySpark Dataframe having names of the elements in a list

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a list of string elements, having around 17k elements. I have to create new columns in a dataframe having integer 0 as all their elements and the columns should have the names of the elements present in the list.

How do i do this?

Example list

```
['V1045','71752','31231']
```

Format required:

```
ID    V1045   71752    31231
1     0       0        0
2     0       0        0
3     0       0        0
4     0       0        0
```

The dataframe has around 700,000 rows.

Comment: This is very unclear. Please include examples of your data as well as the code you've tried to write

Comment: @ErnestKiwele Is the question clear now?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily generate that data:

This list will be used for column names:

```python
l = ['ID', 'V1045','71752','31231']
```

Then a range with required indices is created, with static zeroes used as values:

```python
df = sc.parallelize(range(700000))\
       .map(lambda l: [l, 0, 0, 0])\
       .toDF(l)
```

When you call `.show()`, it returns something like:

```python
+---+-----+-----+-----+
| ID|V1045|71752|31231|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
|  0|    0|    0|    0|
|  1|    0|    0|    0|
|  2|    0|    0|    0|
|  3|    0|    0|    0|
|  4|    0|    0|    0|
+---+-----+-----+-----+
only showing top 5 rows
```

Comment: You could also use `sc.range()` for example: `df = sc.range(100).map(lambda x: [x] + [0]*len(l)).toDF(["ID"] + l)`

Comment: @ErnestKiwele see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709440/5858851) for a detailed explanation of why `sc.range()` is better.

Answer (score 0):

If you already had a dataframe, the easiest way to add columns is to use `withColumn()`. You can add the value `0` to every row using [`pyspark.sql.functions.lit()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lit).

For example:

```python
l = ['V1045','71752','31231']
for new_col in l:
    df = df.withColumn(new_col, f.lit(0))

df.show(n=5)
#+---+-----+-----+-----+
#| ID|V1045|71752|31231|
#+---+-----+-----+-----+
#|  0|    0|    0|    0|
#|  1|    0|    0|    0|
#|  2|    0|    0|    0|
#|  3|    0|    0|    0|
#|  4|    0|    0|    0|
#+---+-----+-----+-----+
#only showing top 5 rows
```

Remember that spark is lazy, so these operations are not happening in a loop as shown here.

```python
df.explain()
#== Physical Plan ==
#*Project [ID#111L, 0 AS V1045#114, 0 AS 71752#118, 0 AS 31231#123]
#+- Scan ExistingRDD[ID#111L]
```

You probably shouldn't use `sc.parallelize(range())`, especially if you're using python 2 as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48709440/5858851).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the thing is, I tried this and it was not successful just because of the sheer size of the dataframe that will be made. There are about 700,000 rows and around 17,000 new columns (The list has 17,000 string elements) have to be added, which leads me to a memory error.

Comment: I don't have documentation to back this up (will look for it) but Spark does not scale well for wide DataFrames (in practice I have found the limit to be around 1400 columns, but I suppose it depends on the size of the data). You can have as many rows as you want because rows are split amongst executors, but a single row is not split. You may want to consider breaking your DataFrame into multiple tables and using an ID as a primary key to join them.

Comment: Or maybe you should look into [`SparseVector`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.SparseVector) or [`DenseVector`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector). There's likely a better way to do what you're trying to do.